# Check if an NSTask is creating files

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, nstask

I am executing an executable in Cocoa using NSTask. The executable is creating files.
Is there any way I can find out which files are created by this executable during its execution ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool in Instruments that allows you to trace all file accesses by a program, and there's a guide to using it in the online manual [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MonitoringOSXAppBehaviors/MonitoringOSXAppBehaviors.html).